# How do I get large cover photos for springpad notebooks?

Tags: springpad

My question is exactly what the title says. It seems that the new web version of Springpad update allows for large notebook cover photos, but I can't figure out how to set them to appear this way. (I was *going* to provide nice images illustrating, but apparently I can't do that as a new user, so links will have to suffice)

These are my [public notebooks](http://springpad.com/#!/jatheis2), which I hope you all can see. Note that all the cover images are small.

The [Spotlight notebooks on Springpad.com](http://springpad.com/#!/) have what I want. I have no idea how it was done or if it is even possible for my own personal notebooks. Note that the top image is large in size, making the whole notebook cover "taller".

I have tried the notebook settings, which only seem to allow you to activate or deactivate automatic images. Also, I tried various editing options on a photo within the notebook, "liking" a photo within, etc, to no avail. Ideally I'd like to be able to choose which photo is the big one, but even having it choose one at random (like how it chooses the would be a start).

Comment: Your best bet for an answer might be on their support site: https://getsatisfaction.com/springpartners

Comment: Yes, I've tried that in the past, usually for bugs though. As long as they answer "how-to's" as well, I suppose I'm ok. Thanks for adding the Springpad tag for me, I tried to create it myself, but alas I am not cool enough yet on Web Applications.

Comment: [My Question](https://getsatisfaction.com/springpartners/topics/how_do_i_get_large_cover_photos_for_springpad_notebooks) hasn't gotten much attention, but here it is for reference. So if anyone figures it out before the Springpad people do, please post it here!

Comment: [Springpad is ceasing operations June 25, 2014](https://springpad.com/blog/2014/05/announcement-springpad-shutting-down/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like this is not possible. According to the Springpad people, the "large photo" cover for notebooks is something they do on their end, and only for spotlighted notebooks. They do however say its an option they want to add for the future for users.

See the [official Springpad response](https://getsatisfaction.com/springpartners/topics/how_do_i_get_large_cover_photos_for_springpad_notebooks) by support employee Devin to my question.